# Call parent function from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

so i have a slider and a method to stop the slider and restart the slider, but i need to stop the slider based on the state of the children, so if the user press the child component the state change and i need to stop the slider but that function is in the slider component how can i call that function from the child this is my child component.

```
class SliderPromotions extends React.Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();
        this.state =
        {
            Promotion: false
        }
    }

    ShowPromotion = () =>
    {
        this.setState({ Promotion: !this.state.Promotion });
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
        <Slider StopSlider={this.state.Promotion}>
        {
            Data.map(function(DataValue)
            {
                return (
                    <Child onPress={() => this.ShowPromotion()}/>
                );
            }, this)
        }
        </Slider>
        );
    }

}
```

This is the slider component, when the state of the child is true will stop the slider and when is false will restart the slider

```
class Slider extends React.Component
{
     StopSlider = () =>
     {
        //this stop the slider
        //.......
        //I try this when I pass the prop but doesn't work
        if(!this.props.StopSlider)
        {
             
        }
     }

     RestartSlider = () =>
     {
         //this restart the slider
     }
     render()
     {
           return (
            <ScrollView>
                {
                    this.props.children
                }
            </ScrollView>
           );
     }

}
```

so i try to pass a prop from the SliderPromotion in the Slider component like this "StopSlider={this.state.Promotion}" but don't work properly

I am thinking the way you should do this is pass the function to the children and then the children call that function but I don't know how to do it if I have this.props.chlidren

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the function to you child component like this:

```
<Child onPress={() => this.pressHandler()}/>
```

And you have to add a function pressHandler to your component SliderPromotions.

```
 pressHandler= () =>
    {
      // Add your logic when the state Promotion is false
      // Add your logic when the state Promotion is true
    }
```

Comment: that is the thing if i put <Child /> i need to create a component, i am using this.props.children because i need something more dynamic, i cant create another component

Comment: I mean you have to like this:
   render()
    {
        return (
        <Slider StopSlider={this.state.Promotion}>
        {
            Data.map(function(DataValue)
            {
                return (
                    <Child onPress={() => this.ShowPromotion()}  StopSlider={this.StopSlider}/>
                );
            }, this)
        }
        </Slider>
        );
    }, it will stay dynamic :), so you have change the component SliderPromotions with that code.

Comment: that don't make sense mi child component is a TouchableOpacity component in react native, is a button, and i dont see it even if is a custom component

Comment: If its a button you can bind the click event or any event to the function StopSlider.

Comment: how can i bind that. onpress is like onclick in normal react

Comment: If the click event is like a press event, so bind it with the function pressHandler(You need to create it), inside this function you will check if Promotion state is false then it will become true and if the state is true you will add your desired logic.